# Firefox changes fileextension to ".csv.htm." when downloading a csv from myapp (php/phpexcel)

Tags: php, csv, firefox, phpexcel

My app (php/phpExcel) provides a download function for a .csv file. When I download the file with chrome or IE all is ok, but when I use Firefox for the download it changes the fileextension to ".csv.htm", then Excel asks how to open because the extension and the fileformat wont fit together.

```php
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename="csvdownload_'.date("Y-m-d_H_i_s").'.csv');
    echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM

    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed

    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); 
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0



    $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
    $objWriter->setDelimiter(';');
    $objWriter->setEnclosure('"');
    $objWriter->setLineEnding("\r\n");

    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the headers shown below and all browsers should be happy and download the file as a CSV. If you haven't calculated the number of bytes simply leave that header out.

```
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="Your_File_Name_Here.csv"');
header('Content-length: ' . $FileBytes);
header('Content-type: application/octetstream');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
```